# Find number in database

Tags: android, android-contacts

i have a number stored in my local contacts like

Xyz
9986799867

Now, i will read this and store it in my DB like

---

1  | xyz  | 9986799867

Suppose if i get call, it will be like +919986799867

My search fails, because there is a mismatch +91 is present in incoming number but not the local database.

If i do same search on contacts DB like,

```
Cursor cursor = ct.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
```

It provides correct name. This is system search, can you tell how its handled internally

Comment: most likely, it just trys to match the last n digits.

Comment: Nope, in india u can save numbers like +919986799867 or 09986799867 all are valid format. in this case how to solve?

Comment: While adding  contact to database make sure it is in correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare a number containing the country code with a number that doesnt't in Java by using the following library :

libphonenumber-6.2.2.jar

With this library you can use **isNumberMatch** which returns true if the numbers match.

you can find out more here :

[LibPhoneNnumber GitHub](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

Comment: like this lib, will give me the number appending country code. i.e if i pass 9986799867 does it appends and returns +91-9986799867?

Comment: Sry i think i misunderstood your comment...is your goal to compare 2 phone numbers even if one contains country code and the other doesnt?

Comment: Na, my requirement is. In my local contacts i have a number i.e 9986799867. I'll store it to my local db as 9986799867. Now i will get incoming call, this time number would be +919986799867. So, now if i query my local db as `select * from tbl where num = "+919986799867"`. It fails because of mismatch of comparison. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Also, adding to my previous comment. Number can be stored to my local db as 09986799867, 919986799867. In these cases, how to compare and fetch the exact row?

Comment: Exactly...the library i suggested does that..it is able ti compare the numbers ..try it it works flawlessly

Comment: But, i need to check if the number exist in local db or not. Without number how can i check?. first i need number, for that i need to pass input to db ie +919986799867. how to handle this case?

Comment: You have to loop through the numbers stores in the local db and use the library isNumberMatch until a match us found

Comment: How to import this in android application?

Comment: Undortunately u cant use sql statements with this library... Now to use it..what IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse sir, i tried to import, its not at all detecting

Comment: Strange in eclipse you only have to put the jar file in the libs folder and add it to the classpath...if you need in an hr i hit the office and provide you with a working example since i used this library before

Comment: Wow, great... thanks for your support. ill wait. let me know once u reach office. meantime i will try myself.. thanks

Comment: I got tat lib, i m trying some sample code, ill post u update

Comment: Great !! gluck, should you need some help im available

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. actually i could not find the latest jar in git folder, i googled with the .jar name you have provided and found the same is mavan repository. where exactly its resided in git folder

Comment: i have accepted your answer, can you tell me about this actually i could not find the latest jar in git folder, i googled with the .jar name you have provided and found the same is mavan repository. where exactly its resided in git folder

Comment: Tell you the truth last time i used it the git repisitary was not yet publushed...i checked the git and i will check the git and report back

Comment: This is the latest version.. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/libphonenumber/7.0.1/libphonenumber-7.0.1-javadoc.jar

Comment: Oh, cool. thank you. I'm passing my country local and number to the lib. If there is no country code beside to number it ads default country code, else it format with passed country code. Nice lib.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: First find the mobile number length it's 10 means directly call select query otherwise use substring method get last 10 digit number after call select query 
Option 2: Save the mobile no with country code